# How do I compare chars (or strings) using void functions, also comparing chars that were taken from a struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, struct, void

I need to compare the different types of data contained within the following structure:

```
struct Person{
    string surname;
    char BType;
    string organ;
    int age;
    int year, ID;
} Patient[50], Donor[50];
```

These structures are being initialized using the following file:

```
Patients 3
Androf B kidney 24 2012
Blaren O kidney 35 2010
Cosmer A heart 35 2007
```

...where the fields are surname, BType, organ, age, year, respectively.

If I want to compare the `BType` of `Patient[1]` with `BType` of `Donor[1]`, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Did you try `Patient[1].BType == Donor[1].BType`? What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a structure containing several members of different types and you are looking for a way how you could compare instances of this struct.

It could look the following way:

```
struct X {
    std::string s;
    char c;
    int i;
    bool operator==(const X& ref) {
        return s == ref.s && c == ref.c && i == ref.i;
    }
    bool operator!=(const X& ref) {
        return !this->operator==(ref);
    }
};
```

possible usage:

```
X x1, x2;
x1.s = x2.s = "string";
x1.c = x2.c = 'c';
x1.i = x2.i = 1;
if (x1 == x2)
    std::cout << "yes";
x1.s = "string2";
if (x1 != x2)
    std::cout << " no";
```

outputs `yes no` since at first all members were equal but later strings differed.

---

However if you just need to compare specific members, access and compare them directly (there's no need of overloading `operator==`):

```
if (Patient[1].BType == Donor[1].BType) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: wow...can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks a bunch, helped a lot. :)